# What is the best algorithm to calculate x^y (x raised to the power y)?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/

here is the simple implementation of this problem by dividing the power by 2. thats mean time complexity of this solution become O(logn[base2]).

Now my question is if we can improve this by dividing the power by 3, that would be O(logn[base3]) which is better than O(logn[base2]), right? but number of multiplications are increased.

So can we find an optimum value "P" such that `y/P` would be better (i mean divide the power by P). how can I find this value 'P'.

And also we are storing the result of recursive call in a temp variable so there is same number of recursive call as in we have while dividing by 2. so we shouldn't be worry about stack-over-flow ;)

Comment: "O(logn[base3]) which is better than O(logn[base2])". No, they are exactly the same.

Comment: By definition of Big-O, and due to the fact that algorithms with different bases differ by a constant factor.

Comment: Your intuition is leading you astray. Even though log3(n) is less than log2(n), the amount of work done in each recursion increases, so the total time taken will be *more*. And the difference between log3(n) and log2(n) doesn't enter into Big-O calculations anyway, as mentioned by many others.

Comment: `log2(n) = log3(n) / log3(2) = k * log3(n)`. Constant factor are not expressed in big-o notation.

Comment: Actually, the fastest algorithm is probably to precalculate all of the non-trivial answers that don't overflow and store them in a jagged array.  There aren't that many integer solutions within the range of an unsigned int.

Comment: ^logarithms, not algorithms...

Answer (score 1):

When looking at big O notation for efficiency the difference between O(logn[base2]) and O(logn[base3]) are the same in the big picture. Yes it would be a slightly more efficient program but when you are approaching larger numbers the difference between the two processes is negligible. So when you are trying to make a program more efficient you usually looks to change from O(n^2) to O(log n); that is changing the efficiency of a program by a noticeable amount.

But now to look at your question, theoretically you could have P approach an infinite number taking the log base to higher numbers but this wouldn't make your program much more efficient in the long run, like I said above. So from a practical approach when actually writing this code unless you are running this function millions of times with small values of X and Y the small increase in efficiency you would get from increasing the value of P isn't viable. So to make the code more optimal you would need to look at something else rather than just changing to value of P which in the end is just a constant, and constants are ignored when looking at efficiency.

Comment: when looking at the o-notation, O(logn[base2]) == O(logn[base3]).

Answer (score 0):

Big-O-Notation ignores constant factors, so O(logn[base3]) = O(log n / log 3) = O(log n / log 2) = O(logn[base2]).

Division by 2 is favored because the constant factor improves a lot. Division by 2 is simply a right-shift, division by 3 would be a floating point operation.

As you also have to consider the remainder of the division, any larger number than two will have more branches which will also increase the runtime.

Eg. 4 would be the next number with trivial division (right-shift by two bits or lowering the exponent of a floating point number by two), but then the remainder can be either 0 (nothing needs to be done), 1 (result has to be multiplied by x), 2 (result has to be multiplied by x twice) or 3 (result has to be multiplied by x three times).

In total I don't see how to improve this algorithm by increasing P.

Comment: Um, division by 3 can be done with integer math just as easily as division by 2. All of which is totally irrelevant when talking about Big-O notation.

Comment: @MarkRansom integer division in modern cpus is implemented via floating point arithmetic. And yes, it is irrelevant for the O notation (see my first sentence) but the "constant factor [which is ignored by O notation] improves a lot"

Comment: @MarkRansom and i strongly disagree with the "just as easily" part. Division by a power of 2 is much simpler than by any other number.

Comment: @example: "integer division in modern cpus is implemented via floating point arithmetic" <- do you have any links to back up this assertion?

Comment: @MarkDickinson I don't. Sorry if it is not true. The timings are very close though. On a Haswell CPU a single 32 bit DIV instruction takes 22-29 cycles to complete and a (52 bit mantissa) FDIV 20-24 cycles.

Comment: Integer division by a constant is implemented with a very clever multiplication and shift sequence on any decent x86 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There is the well-known algorithm which works in log2 (n) steps, and at each steps squares a number, then optionally multiplies it by x. We can create a very similar algorithm which works in log3 (n) steps, and at each step cubes a number, then optionally multiplies by x or x^2. x^2 would have been calculated during the first cubing.

The first algorithm does either one or two multiplications per step, each with probability 0.5, that is 1.5 multiplications on average. The second algorithm does one cubing which requires two multiplications, plus another multiplication with probability 2/3, or 2 2/3 multiplications on average.

The number of steps in algorithm 2 is smaller by a factor log2 (3) 1.584962, or the average number of multiplications is log2 (x) * 2.666666 / 1.584962 = log2 (x) * 1.6825 which is about 12% more than the first algorithm.

However, you could have a base-4 algorithm, where in each step a number is raised to the fourth power, then optionally multiplied by x, x^2 or x^3. If x^2 and x^3 are calculated ahead, then each step takes on average 2.75 multiplications. For very large n this might be slightly faster than the original algorithm.

Importantly, when you can remove the number of steps by a constant factor, but the steps get more complicated by a constant factor, then you can be sure that the Big-O behaviour isn't going to change, and the actual execution time may go up or down, depending on the exact implementation and hardware.